# STMP Authentication Required

Tags: vb.net, smtpclient

It's work before, but suddenly there was this problem last month. Without changing the code

In my issue is when i trying to send the email with `SmtpClient` In VB.net .It's throw exception error message as

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

Whether I use app password / [less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) also with same error!

Code of below :

```
Using client As New SmtpClient(AccountOption.AccMailSMTP, AccountOption.AccMailPort) 'SMTP: smtp.gmail.com & Port: 587

    message = New MailMessage(ParamEmail, fileReaderEmail) 'From Email & To Email

        Dim rich As New RichEditControl
        Dim test As New MemoryStream(AccountOption.AccMailDefaultContent)

        rich.LoadDocument(test, DocumentFormat.Html)
        message.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(file))
        message.Subject = subject.Name & " For " & IO.Path.GetFileName(debtorFolder)
        message.IsBodyHtml = True
        message.Body = rich.HtmlText

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(ParamEmail, ParamPassword) 'To Email & The Password / App Password
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        client.Timeout = 10000
        client.EnableSsl = True

        Try
            client.Send(message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
End Using
```

The Link i have tried . But it same:

[How do I send an email with Gmail and SmtpClient when the sending account uses two factor authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549936/how-do-i-send-an-email-with-gmail-and-smtpclient-when-the-sending-account-uses-t)

[The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632655/the-server-response-was-5-7-0-authentication-required-learn-more-at)

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of code. We can't copy text from pictures. Post your code as text and format it as code.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, I have changed the picture to text .

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question as I never send email using Gmail but I do have a couple of comments about your code. Firstly, don't ever use `Throw ex`. That will truncate the stack trace on the exception. If you want to rethrow an exception then use just `Throw`. That said, if you really do nothing but rethrow the exception in a `Catch` block (which you may not if this code is simplified) then don't bother with exception handling at all. Secondly, if you create an `Attachment` object then you should be disposing it after the email has been sent.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank for your comments , I will enhance it after .

Comment: check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686992/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticate/58689725#58689725 ... maybe it will be usefull.. it works for me

Comment: Hi @PeterKsenak, your solution is work for me . Thank you :))
It's working now

Answer (score 0):

hi go to your google account in the security panel
[image]

Click on turn off/on access (recommend)

in the opened panel it must be turned on

[image]